# Unity desktop shortcuts display path to file

Tags: unity, desktop-environments, shortcuts

I'm using Unity on Ubuntu 12.04 and something odd has happened to my desktop.
At some point all the icons for all the files on my desktop began to display their path beneath the file name. This is no show stopper but it is visually distracting, and clearly incorrect.
For example the file to_do.txt will show:

(little graphic)
to_do.txt
/home/geoff/Desktop

What setting would control that?
I've poked about a fair bit in MyUnity and gconf and not had any luck with finding a setting that looks right.
Any suggestions about what might set this straight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Nautilus, and in the menu section look for Edit -> Preferences -> Display:  There is a series of settings for what captions should be shown under icons in this menu.

Comment: Perfect Charles, that got it. Naturally it was nautilus and not a Unity thing. I suppose I'd not seen it  because the DT is the only place I use icons.